# No response getting in api after calling function in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am calling createUserData api.i want response in resonse_data variable but i am getting 
**undefined** value after console in resonse_data variable

```
    async createUserData(req, res) {
    var resonse_data =  await verifyOtp(req.body);
    console.log(resonse_data); // undefined
    }


   function verifyOtp(data) {

   var mobile = data.mobile_no;
   var otpval = data.otp_val;

    models.mi_otp_details.findOne({
     where: {
            mi_mobile_no: mobile,
            mi_otp_value:otpval
        }
        }).then(function (otpdetails) {
        if (otpdetails.mi_otp_used_status == '1') 
               {
            var response = ['400', 'OTP Used'];
            return response;            
              }   
        }).catch(function (err) {
          var response = ['400', 'OTP or Mobile No Invalid'];
          return response;             
    });       
    }
```

Comment: You must check the `otpdetails` variable, if the `mi_otp_used_status` is not equal to `1` or `otpdetails` is `null`  the response of method will be undefined

Comment: @pichlou.. I was getting a proper value in otpdetails variable..I got the ans.i have to return the model that's it...Check the ans has given.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 async createUserData(req, res) {
    var resonse_data =  await verifyOtp(req.body);
    console.log(resonse_data); // undefined
    }


   function verifyOtp(data) {

   var mobile = data.mobile_no;
   var otpval = data.otp_val;

    return models.mi_otp_details.findOne({ // <----- HERE!!!
     where: {
            mi_mobile_no: mobile,
            mi_otp_value:otpval
        }
        }).then(function (otpdetails) {
        if (otpdetails.mi_otp_used_status == '1') 
               {
            var response = ['400', 'OTP Used'];
            return response;            
              }   
        }).catch(function (err) {
          var response = ['400', 'OTP or Mobile No Invalid'];
          return response;             
    });       
    }
```

Comment: Yaroslav Gaponov...This solution is working fine..Thanks for help